# Loop array items and limit the display

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

There is an `array` named `$banners` with several data values pulled from my database. For this `array`, I'd like to display only seven of these values. So I:

```
$count = count($banners);
for($count; ; $count++) {
  if($count > 7) {
    break;
  }
  foreach ($banners as $banner) {
    echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner "!</div>"
  }
}
```

The code will display only if the `array` contains less or equal than 7 items. Otherwise, if `array` has more than 7, nothing will appear in the screen.

So, no matter if the code has two or thousand items. Only seven should be printed on the screen! Is there anyway to adjust the loop for it?

Comment: Why do you count `$banners`? Any reason for this?

Comment: `foreach (array_slice($banners, 0, 7) as $banner) { ... }`

Comment: `$banners` is count in order to check how many values the `array` has. If is more than 7 it should break the `<div>` displays and not print more than it.

Comment: Amazing how many excessively complex answers people have posted for something that is essentially trivial

Answer (score 1):

use `min` to display max 7 element, use a `while` loop and `pop` a banner to display:

```
$count = min(7, count($banners)); 
while ($count--) { 
    $banner = array_pop($banners); 
    echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner ."!</div>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
$arraySize = count($banners);
foreach ($banners as $banner) {
    if($count++ < $arraySize)
        echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner "!</div>"
    else break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way, the loop will only iterate 7 times no matter what:

```
$count = count($banners);
for($x = 0; $x < 7; $x++) {
    echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner[$x] . "!</div>"
  }
}
```

The $x is a separate variable for counting the loop iterations, and you can use it to select the nth element from your array.

Comment: if count is lower than 7 => bug

Comment: True that for your purpose you mentioned in the question, you don't need count($banners).

Comment: @G33kGurl Well the loop you(and I) created, will give an `undefined offset` if `count($banners)` is less than 7

Answer (score 0):

It’s quite easy to limit to 7 (or less) iterations on an array and display the results (see other answers). However the glaring question is:

Why aren't you selecting a limit of 7 items from your database?

Answer (score 0):

I think sizeof() function is what you are looking for..

if(sizeof($banners) <= 7) {

```
 foreach ($banners as $banner)
 {
    echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner "!</div>"
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($banners as $key => $banner) 
{
  if($key == 7) 
  {
    break; //Breaking code flow!
  }
  echo "<div>Hey, this is a " . $banner "!</div>"
}
```

Comment: Please add a plain-English explanation of how this solves the problem.